# Constructing primitive cell using information from ChemicalData

Tags: plotting, graphics, curated-data, chemistry

I would like to construct a primitive cell (figure shown) and possibly the two-dimensional layout (figure from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_dichalcogenide_monolayers)) using the following input. Any clues as to how this can be done?

```
ChemicalData["MoS2", "EdgeRules"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "EdgeTypes"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "ElementTypes"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "VertexTypes"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "VertexCoordinates"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "FormalCharges"]

ChemicalData["MoS2", "ElementTally"]
```

[image: MoS2 primitive cell]

[image: MoS2 lattice]

Comment: See also [MaXrd package](https://github.com/Stianpr20/MaXrd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit** *I've included another method for creating the crystal structure which should be useful for pedagogical purposes, but assumes that MoS<sub>2</sub> behaves ideally.*

### Short Answer

It can't be done with `ChemicalData` alone, (as of 2014) since there is important information missing.  We are not given any information about the crystal structure, and therefore need to find additional sources.

### Roll your own

We can try to make our own crystal structure if we have the relevant information.  Here's one way to do it, starting first with a simpler structure, that of sodium chloride, which crystallizes in a face centered cubic lattice.  We can use `LatticeData` to visualize this structure:

```
LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Image"]
```

[image]

We need to [look elsewhere](http://www.webelements.com/sodium/crystal_structure.html) for the unit cell dimensions (the cell dimension is 429 pm) but we can get ionic radii from `WolframAlpha`

```
naradius = 
 QuantityMagnitude@WolframAlpha["sodium ion radius", "WolframResult"]
clradius = 
 QuantityMagnitude@
  WolframAlpha["chloride ion radius", "WolframResult"]
celldim = 429;
```

Now, playing with the lattice above, we can style it for the anions:

```
chloride = 
 LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Image"] /. {Line[_] -> Null, 
   Polygon[_] -> Null, GrayLevel[0] -> Blue, 
   Sphere[x_List, y_] :> Sphere[x, clradius/celldim]}
```

[image]

We do the same thing for the sodium ions and note that these ions are shifted by one half the dimensions of the unit cell.  Putting all of this together gets us:

```
sodium = LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", 
   "Image"] /. {Line[_] -> Null, Polygon[_] -> Null, 
   GrayLevel[0] -> Green, 
   Sphere[x_List, y_] :> Sphere[x, naradius/celldim]}
unitcell = 
 Show[{chloride, 
   Graphics3D[
    GeometricTransformation[sodium[[1]], 
     TranslationTransform[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}]]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

I really like this view, since it clearly shows us that the unit cell contains 4 full ions of sodium, and the 4 chloride ions are counted by noting that each corner is 1/8 an ion and each face is 1/2 an ion. Making a table of transformations gets us a nice looking crystal (that is admittedly inefficient and needs a little bit of cleanup around the edges).

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[
  unitcell[[1]], 
  Flatten@Table[
    TranslationTransform[{i 1, j 1, k 1}], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}, {k, 
     0, 3}]]]
```

### Back to MoS<sub>2</sub>

Molybdenum disulfide is a challenge since it has a hexagonal packing structure with an a-typical coordination.  I think it's best to draw our own unit cell for these purposes. I note from [this paper](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/journal/v3/n6/full/ncomms1882.html) that the metal is encapsulated in a trigonal prismatic cage of sulfur atoms, and the sulfur atoms form an eclipsed hexagonal structure.  The unit cell for this form is a rhombus and we can use [known relationships](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rhombus.html) to get our unit cell.  The dimensions from the paper are a = 3.12 angstroms and the layer spacing is 3.11 angstroms.

```
a = 3.12;
c = 3.11;
p = -2 a Cos[120 Degree];
q = 2 a Sin[120 Degree];

sulfur = Graphics3D[{Yellow, Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 5], 
   Sphere[#, 0.5] & /@ {{0, p/2, c/2}, {0, -p/2, c/2}, {q/2, 0, 
      c/2}, {-q/2, 0, c/2}, {0, p/2, -c/2}, {0, -p/2, -c/2}, {q/2, 
      0, -c/2}, {-q/2, 0, -c/2}}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Let's have *Mathematica* figure out where the Molybdenum is supposed to be, given that we know it is coordinated to 6 of the sulfur atoms.  We'll add some bonds while were at it.

```
coordsulfur = {{0, p/2, c/2}, {0, -p/2, c/2}, {-q/2, 0, c/2}, {0, 
    p/2, -c/2}, {0, -p/2, -c/2}, {-q/2, 0, -c/2}};
momin = NMinimize[
  Total[EuclideanDistance[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ coordsulfur], {x, y, z}]
mopos = {x, y, z} /. momin[[2]]
unitcell = 
 Graphics3D[
  Flatten[{sulfur[[1]], {Blue, Sphere[mopos, 0.4]}, {GrayLevel[0.5], 
     bonds}}], Boxed -> False]
bonds = Tube[{#, mopos}, 0.2] & /@ coordsulfur;
sbonds = Tube[#, 0.2] & /@ {
    {{0, -p/2, c/2}, {-q/2, 0, c/2}},
    {{-q/2, 0, c/2}, {0, p/2, c/2}},
    {{0, p/2, c/2}, {q/2, 0, c/2}},
    {{q/2, 0, c/2}, {0, -p/2, c/2}},
    {{0, -p/2, -c/2}, {-q/2, 0, -c/2}},
    {{-q/2, 0, -c/2}, {0, p/2, -c/2}},
    {{0, p/2, -c/2}, {q/2, 0, -c/2}},
    {{q/2, 0, -c/2}, {0, -p/2, -c/2}},
    {{q/2, 0, -c/2}, {q/2, 0, c/2}},
    {{-q/2, 0, -c/2}, {-q/2, 0, c/2}},
    {{0, p/2, -c/2}, {0, p/2, c/2}},
    {{0, -p/2, -c/2}, {0, -p/2, c/2}},
    {{0, -p/2, c/2}, {0, p/2, c/2}},
    {{0, -p/2, -c/2}, {0, p/2, -c/2}}
    };
```

[image]

One can perform a `GeometricTransformation` on this unit cell to get the expanded crystal structure; however this is the part that I don't like, so I'll sleep on it before adding to this already-too-long answer.

### Update, another crystal structure fabrication process

I've thought a bit about the MoS<sub>2</sub> crystal structure, and here's how I came about some pictures.  Start with the hcp lattice from curated data.  Grab the spheres and (manually) select the 8 that represent the unit cell.  We also need to adjust the z height (to 1 instead of 2) and add the Mo atom in the appropriate place.

```
hcp = LatticeData["HexagonalClosePacking", "Image"];
spheres = Cases[hcp[[1]], Sphere[x_, y_] :> x, Infinity];
unitcellspheres = spheres[[ {1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 15}]];
unitcellspheres[[All, 3]] = 
  unitcellspheres[[All, 3]] /. {1 -> 0.5, -1 -> -0.5};
csphere = {-1/2, 1/(2 Sqrt[3]), 0};
```

Now, I find it easiest to use a `GraphicsComplex` to make the first figure.

```
unitcell = GraphicsComplex[Join[unitcellspheres, {csphere}],
   {
    (* 'global' directives *)
    Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 9],
    (* sulfur atoms*)
    {Yellow, Table[Sphere[i, 0.1], {i, 1, 8}]},
    (* sulfur 'bonds' *)
    {Yellow, 
     Tube[#, 0.03] & /@ {{1, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {5, 
        7}, {7, 8}, {8, 6}, {6, 5}, {7, 6}, {1, 5}, {2, 6}, {3, 
        7}, {4, 8}}},
    (* Mo *)
    {Blue, Sphere[9, 0.1]},
    (* Mo bonds Mo side*)
    {Blue, 
     GeometricTransformation[ Tube[{#, 9}, 0.03], 
        ScalingTransform[0.5, unitcellspheres[[#]] - csphere, 
         csphere]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}},
    (* Mo bonds S side *)
    {Yellow,
     GeometricTransformation[ Tube[{#, 9}, 0.03], 
        ScalingTransform[0.5, unitcellspheres[[#]] - csphere, 
         unitcellspheres[[#]]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}

    }] // Graphics3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The remaining figures can be made using `GeometricTransformation` of the unit cell, and I wrap that into a `Manipulate` to have some fun.  I've created another unitcell (`unitcell2`) that doesn't have the sulfur-sulfur bonds shown in the previous figure.

```
unitcell2 =  GraphicsComplex[Join[unitcellspheres, {csphere}],
    {
     (* 'global' directives *)
     Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 9],
     (* sulfur atoms*)
     {Yellow, Table[Sphere[i, 0.1], {i, 1, 8}]},
     (* Mo *)
     {Blue, Sphere[9, 0.1]},
     (* Mo bonds *)
     {GrayLevel[0.5], Tube[{#, 9}, 0.05] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7}}

     }] // Graphics3D;
Manipulate[Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[unitcell2[[1]],
   Flatten@{
     TranslationTransform[{0, 0, 0}],
     Table[
      TranslationTransform[{j 0.5 + i, j Sqrt[3]/2 + Mod[k, 2], 
        2 k }], {i, 0, imax}, {j, 0, jmax}, {k, 0, kmax}]
     }], SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False], {imax, 0, 5, 
  1}, {jmax, 0, 5, 1}, {kmax, 0, 3, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat! BTW, if one wants CPK coloring, `ColorData["Atoms"]` has the needed colors.