# How to change the atom size of LatticeData

Tags: graphics, curated-data, lattices

Using the `"Image"` property of [`LatticeData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LatticeData.html), I can generate representation of lattice structures (like the first basic example did). But it seems that the atom size is a constant, can I enlarge it?

Maybe I want a simple expression of something like [this](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CubicCrystalLattices/). This demonstration also has the limitation that atom size cannot be larger than $1/2$ of face diagonal.

Comment: A replacement rule such as `LatticeData[lattice, "Image"] /. Sphere[cents_, r_] :> Sphere[cents, 2 r]` might work.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Yes, it works. I'd like to endorse your answer if you want to write it down. I was wondering why this transformation on Sphere works. Is Sphere a property of LatticeData? I can't find it in the documentation. Sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm new to Mathematica. Thank you!

Comment: For a number of reasons (e.g. no computer), I do not have the time to write an answer, so I'll have to ask you to answer your own question. To see why it works, have a look at `InputForm[LatticeData[(* stuff *)]]` to see what it's made of, and you should be able to figure out why the dilation replacement did what it did.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I got it! Thanks again. I'll write an answer later tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guesswhoitis gave a nice solution to this problem on the comments above:

```
LatticeData[lattice, "Image"] /. Sphere[cents_, r_] :> Sphere[cents, 2 r]
```

Specifically, I did

```
LatticeData["SimpleCubic", "Image"] /. Sphere[cents_, r_] -> Ball[cents, 24 r]
```

[image]

(I also transformed spheres to balls here). It works because if you take a look at the `InputForm[]` of `LatticeData[lattice, "Image"]`, it's something like this:

```
Graphics3D[
    { GraphicsComplex[{{-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}}, 
    { EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.8]], Opacity[0.1], Polygon[{{8, 4, 2, 6}, {8, 6, 5, 7}, {8, 7, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, 
    {1, 3, 7, 5}, {2, 1, 5, 6}}]}], 
    { GrayLevel[0], Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 5], 
    { Sphere[{-1, -1, -1}, 1.44], Sphere[{-1, -1, 1}, 1.44], Sphere[{-1, 1, -1}, 1.44], 
    Sphere[{-1, 1, 1}, 1.44], Sphere[{1, -1, -1}, 1.44], Sphere[{1, -1, 1}, 1.44], 
    Sphere[{1, 1, -1}, 1.44], Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1.44]}}}, 
    Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {4, 5/3, 1}
]
```

And you can transform the spheres, manipulating their radii and positions.

Comment: Also, here is [another relevant answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/constructing-primitive-cell-using-information-from-chemicaldata).